# What does MATE do on suspend and how to change it to pm-suspend

Tags: suspend, power-management, mate, 21.04

In Ubuntu Mate 21.04 suspending with `sudo pm-suspend` works perfectly. But using the power button does not work.

The dialog *Power Management Preferences* shows *When the power button is pressed: Suspend*, but nothing happens when I press the power button.

When I change the value to *Ask me*, the dialog where one can choose to shut down or suspend pops up, and thus I know that the button itself works. However, when I choose *Suspend* in this dialog, again nothing happens.

I have already searched the related values in `dconf-editor`, but without success.

Question: Which command does Mate launch on suspend and how can I change it to `pm-suspend`?

Comment: I would also recommend to ask on http://ubuntu-mate.community/ .

Answer (score 0):

Dead thread and no one linked to ubuntu-mate community, but this thread showed up on DuckDuckGo.

I found the issue I was having was due to Light Locker trying to Lock the session *after* suspend, which immediately both woke the system from S3 sleep and then then seeming locked out of Mate's already configured "Suspend on lid close". My solution was to disable "lock after suspend" via
Control Center -> Light Locker Settings -> Lock on Suspend (the last option)

S3 sleep now functions as expected, AND Ubuntu Mate still manages to lock the session automatically anyway (via light locker)

I did a little more digging and on my install,

Ubuntu MATE 22.04 jammy
  mate-session 1.26.0
  light-locker 1.8.0
  lightdm 1.30.0
  systemd 249 (249.11-0ubuntu3.12)
  pm-utils 1.4.1-19

pm-suspend and systemctl start suspend.target both work, I tried to search through systemd's service target and sockets related to sleep and suspend, but I couldn't find any reference to light locker and few references to locking.

The issue appears to simply be two configurations both telling light locker to lock at different times.